# How to check for command that has been defined later?

Tags: macros

How to only run a part of code if the condition is only created afterwards?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\ifdefined\abc
\RequirePackage{pdfpages} 
\setkomavar{specialmail}{\textbf{\abc}}
\fi

\newcommand{\abc}{ABCtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{address}
    \opening{Hello,}
        content
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Even though `abc`is defined the condition is not resolved as true... How can I fix it?

P.S.: In my real example I want to use the part on top to include the stamp from a file and put that in an .lco file.

Comment: tex does not have the document in memory. If you want a forward reference you need to write to the aux file at the end and pick it up on the next run, but that is not visible until `\begin{document}`

Comment: or use `\AtBeginDocument{\ifdefined\abc
\RequirePackage{pdfpages} 
\setkomavar{specialmail}{\textbf{\abc}}
\fi}` so the test happens later

Comment: @DavidCarlisle packages should imho better use the previous hook, nameref e.g. would error there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes I wondered about that, old habits:-) maybe I'll post a begindocument/before answer

Comment: Clearly, the solution in your example is to change the order so that `\abc` is defined first.  You've decided you can't do that in your real example, but I'm not understanding your rationale for that decision.

Comment: @Teepeemm: I want to put the complicated part of cutting out the stamp from the pdf file into the .lco file and then in my document only define the stamp.pdf name. If I do not define it then don't add a stamp to the letter... That's why I can't just reverse the order...

Comment: @Teepeemm usually the test is in a class, and the definition is user-code in preamble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay the test, for example to the end of the preamble.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{%
\ifdefined\abc
\RequirePackage{pdfpages} 
\setkomavar{specialmail}{\textbf{\abc}}
\fi
}


\newcommand{\abc}{ABCtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{address}
    \opening{Hello,}
        content
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you!